# custom function not taking place, but alert before it is

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom function that is defined just like another custom function. The second custom function works, but the first custom function doesn't.

The difference is that the first custom function happens in an if-condition.

I thought there was something wrong with my if-condition, but it seems to be working as the alert inside it firing. Just the custom function inside it is not.

Here is my code:

```
$('#tabViewWindow').pep({
axis:'x',
useCSSTranslation:false,
drag:function(ev, obj){

    if(obj.dx>0 && obj.$el.offset().left>=$(window).width()*0.6){
    /*alert("slide here");*/
    slideLeft(ev, obj);
    }
    handleOpacity(ev, obj);
},
});
function handleOpacity(ev, obj){
var opacity = 1 - (parseInt(obj.$el.css('left'))/$(window).width());
obj.$el.css('opacity', opacity);
}
function slideLeft(ev, obj){
    obj.$el.animate({left:'100%'});
}
```

The first custom function is `handleOpacity()`. That works. The second custom function is `slideLeft()`. That does not work. But the alert before the calling of `slideLeft()`, which is currently commented out, works fine.

How can I get `slideLeft()` to occur in the condition?

**Update:** Here is a JS Fiddle that recreates my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/bccQh/1/

I am trying to slide #tabViewWindow to the right, by giving it left:100%, if it is 60% off screen or more.

Comment: if you have a alert inside slideLeft() do you get it?

Comment: Your question is not precise enough for anyone to help, you might consider adding a jsfiddle to help people figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: If "position:static", the left property has no effect.

Comment: @roasted Nope, it is position:absolute;

Comment: @Sergio Nope, alert inside doesn't fire.

Comment: @FlorianF. I have included a JS Fiddle where the problem is recreated. I updated my question. Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bccQh/1/

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/bccQh/3/ and drag your black square to the right, out of screen.

Comment: @Sergio the alert happens, but the item doesn't slide off screen. What I'm trying to do is on release, if it is 60% or more off screen then slide it off screen by animating to `left:100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animate gets in conflict with the animate used by jquery-pep.

You have to return false on the drag function whenever you don't want pep to control your div anymore :

```
drag:function(ev, obj){
        if(obj.dx>0 && obj.$el.offset().left>=$(window).width()*0.6){
            slideLeft(ev, obj);
            return false;
        }
        handleOpacity(ev, obj);
    },
```

The behaviour is not really smooth but it does what you expect.

http://jsfiddle.net/V6Ypt/

Comment: Thank you! Ah, I see. Well, I need this to happen on the stop and rest event, when the drag is done and let go, not the drag event. I think that will make it smoother. I tried adding return false to my code, but it not happening. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/bccQh/7/